# Error in pytesseract while running in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, google-colaboratory, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

I have installed tesseract in Google colab using the command

```
!pip3 install pytesseract
!pip3 install tesseract-ocr
!sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

Then I ran the command

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'

pytesseract.image_to_string(img,  lang='eng', config=r'--oem 3 --psm 7')
```

Then I got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TesseractError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3e07674434a3> in <module>()
      3 
----> 4 pytesseract.image_to_string(im_bw,  lang='eng', config=r'--oem 3 --psm 7')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    234     with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:
    235         if proc.returncode:
--> 236             raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
    237 
    238 

TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')
```

Comment: I have the same error.

Comment: @RafaelLima I am still unaware of the solution, please let me know if you find it. Thank You                                                                                                                        By the way, what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/bin/tesseract'

img = r"/content/gdrive/MyDrive/images.jpg"

result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img)))
print(result)
```

You should specify the 'img path' before this line;
`pytesseract.image_to_string(img,  lang='eng', config=r'--oem 3 --psm 7')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).